# regular expression with exactly one substring of 111

Tags: regex

I have to come up with Regular Expression for the language all strings over binary alphabet {0,1} with exactly one occurrence of the substring 111 ?

so I came with up with this RE `(0+1)*111(0+1)*`

Need help whether my RE is correct for exactly one occurrence of the substring 111 ?

Comment: Have you tried it on some sample strings? Try it on some strings which have exactly one 111 and some which have multiple 111 and see what they do.

Comment: Not sure you'll be able to do this with a regular expression alone. The easiest way would be to search for how many times `111` occurs in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a positive look ahead for the required part and a negative look ahead for the restricted part:

```
^(?=.*111)(?!(.*111){2})[01]+$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/6ijXISAZ6O) of this regex working with some edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to cover the language:

```
(0|110|10)*111(0|011|01)*
```

Comment: what about 01,111 and 011,111?

Comment: do you mean that the comma is included in the alphabet?

Comment: No, I placed comma just to show where '111' is ->
01111 and 011111

Comment: all alternatives before 111 end with 0 so your inputs are rejected